# Why does it fail to find a div ? (simple_html_dom)

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have this code:

```
<?php
//Include simple_html_dom.php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

//Get function and variable for Webpage
$Flightnumber = '**********';
$firstprelink = '*********************************';
$secondprelink = $Flightnumber;
$fulllink = $firstprelink.$secondprelink;
$html = file_get_html($fulllink, false);
$firstone = $html->find("div[id=********]");
echo $firstone;
?>
```

Why doesn´t it work ? It should display the div´s of the page.
On other webpages it works and when I echo only `$html` it works fine too.
I don´t understand.
It just ouputs this:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sofort-Flug-Entschädigung\simpletest3.php on line 17
>   Array

Comment: The content is delivered by Javascript I think so you'd need to use something like node.js or a headless browser

Comment: no wait, how is that possible if It echos the whole html without problems, that makes no sense

Comment: does it - ok. I tried loading that page in a browser but nothing, other than the main layout, rendered so I made the assumption I'm afraid

Comment: even the tracking map work, so I don´t think the javascript on that site is the problem

Comment: ok - I stand corrected - my apologies for misleading you

Comment: no problem, noticed it right after, but what the heck could the problem be, it´s the first Page I have these problems on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So the Solution:**

For some unkown reason I needed to find the div/tag I was searching for by counting it:

```
$firstone = $html->find('div');
$secondone = $firstone[2];
```

Further: echo; did not work so I used "print();".

That´s it, so:

1) Find tag by counting.
2) Print, don´t echo.

```
print($secondone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get more than one div ref  in your $firstone  then you are try to echo an array

so try accessing the first element as

```
echo $firstone[0];
```

Comment: seems you changed  the question  .. this not fair  ...if my fisrt answer is correct you should rate it properly and post a new question as a separated  question  in a new post .

Comment: Agree with scaisEdge. Please don't change your question and invalidate answers that have been given or efforts that have been made.

Comment: You comment mean that you are tryinng to accessing the an elem in an array that is not available  .. could be you have on result only antry to accessing to second eg in a loop

Comment: so you don't want wait for your time but you are looking for the time of others persons.. i think you should think deep a this  .............. if we think only at our time we don't answer  to you